# Standard way for importing Zustand properties in React

Tags: reactjs, zustand

Is there an easier way to import Zustand properties and assign them in a react component?

Ex: This is the logic in ComponentA.tsx

```
const { propA, propB, propC,...,propZ } = useStore(state => (
  propA: state.propA,
  propB: state.propB,
  .
  .
  propZ: state.propZ
), shallow);
```

Instead of multiple local variables like `propA` and `propB`. What is the standard way to import?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by `import`. Would something like that work for you? `const full = useStore(state => (
 ...state
), shallow);

console.log(full.propA);`
Maybe you can use the spread operator `...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Fetching everything

The simplest way, but you will import all the data (I don't know is it will affect the performance or not)

```
const App = () => {
    const state = useStore()
    return {
      <>
        <h1>{state.title}</h1>
        <p>{state.paragraph}</p>
      </>
  }
}
```

### Selecting multiple state slices

```
const title = useStore((state) => state.title)
const paragraph = useStore((state) => state.paragraph)
```

It detects changes with strict-equality (old === new) by default, this is efficient for atomic state picks.

```
const nuts = useStore((state) => state.nuts)
const honey = useStore((state) => state.honey)
```

If you want to construct a single object with multiple state-picks inside, similar to redux's mapStateToProps, you can tell zustand that you want the object to be diffed shallowly by passing the shallow equality function.

```
import shallow from 'zustand/shallow'

// Object pick, re-renders the component when either state.nuts or state.honey change
const { nuts, honey } = useStore(
  (state) => ({ nuts: state.nuts, honey: state.honey }),
  shallow
)

// Array pick, re-renders the component when either state.nuts or state.honey change
const [nuts, honey] = useStore((state) => [state.nuts, state.honey], shallow)

// Mapped picks, re-renders the component when state.treats changes in order, count or keys
const treats = useStore((state) => Object.keys(state.treats), shallow)
For more control over re-rendering, you may provide any custom equality function.

const treats = useStore(
  (state) => state.treats,
  (oldTreats, newTreats) => compare(oldTreats, newTreats)
)
```

src: https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand#recipes